# Why was this question closed as opinion-based? (“Why do bond markets close slightly early (at 2 p.m. ET) on December 31 vs. the stock market”)

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Why was this question “[Why do bond markets close slightly early (at 2 p.m. ET) on December 31 whereas the stock market closes at the regular time? [closed]](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/134451/5656)
” closed as opinion-based?

There could be some objective answer, [such as](https://qr.ae/pNxCmw) (from [Michael Malone](https://www.quora.com/profile/Michael-Malone-49)):

> The bond market (even US-based) is primarily an international market. The rest of the world, especially Europe and Asia were already drinking champagne out of each other's slippers.

The question has 2 close votes, and 4 reopen votes, but is closed because one of the close votes comes from a moderator.

Answer (score 1):

Unless someone was sitting in the room when the decision was made they have no idea why something is the way it is. That's the general problem with almost all questions that start with the word "why" on this site.

Comment: Why-questions are very often answerable. In the given an example, it is likely that the information was made public since I assume many traders or other finance professionals wonder about it as well.

Comment: Why questions almost always illicit speculative and/or opionated answers. Your own answer to this question is just a speculation. Why is the market closed on Christmas? Because it's a holiday. But why that holiday and not this other holiday? Just speculate and take a guess, and nevermind that the question has basically no value to personal finance or investing. Why isn't the stock market open 24/7? Who cares?

Comment: anyone with some slight amount of curiosity would care. Answers to why question can be grounded in reference statements or logic, for example.

Comment: I don't even know what grounded in reference statements means.

Comment: e.g. official statements

Comment: In fact `The question has 2 close votes, and 4 reopen votes, but is closed because one of the close votes comes from a moderator.` is the answer to this question and you wrote it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your example answer is an opinion. It isn't backed by anything more than a guess.

And that is my guess as to why you answer was closed

If I had been given the chance I would have also voted to close.

Comment: You are confusing guess with opinion. Also, I assume that at some point someone working for the bond market gave some explanation. Opinion-based questions are very much different, e.g. "I have 1000 USD, what should I invest in?"